# Headshot = instant kill?

Tags: brain, human-anatomy, neuroanatomy

While whatching a film, I've been thinking about how does a headshot kill someone, and how long does it take?

For example let's say you've beeing shot by a normal (police) handfired weapon - no shotgun or sniper weapon.

I know that the rhombencephalon regulate the most important vital functions like breathing and if the shoot goes throught it, that there will be no change.

**Question:**
But if the bullet passed the brain throught the telencephalon, which function is mainly thinking, and don't hurt any 
brain regions who handles life keeping functions (like the rhombencephalon)  do you die instantly (like in movies) or have any change (fall into a coma)?

Comment: Depends on which part of the head is hit (and bullet ballistics). Headshot=instant death only happens in Counter Strike :P

Comment: Of course I know, that it depends on which way a bullet go, but in case of it passed the lobus frontalis and damage not the highly critical functions whould there be a change?

Comment: Heard of the famous case of Phineas Gage? He survived but apparently his entire personality changed.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me, because the lobus frontalis handles emotions, personality, humor, ... and when it gets damaged some variables can be changed.

Comment: IMO this question is less about biology than ballistics. The effect of destroying a particular structure in the brain is probably known, including the likelihood of instant death (whatever that means). The likelihood that a bullet causes such damage is a separate question.

Comment: On my first day of an ER rotation (Charity Hospital in New Orleans), a man *walked into the ER* with a chief complaint of "I was shot in the head." Sure enough, he had a bullet hole directly in the middle of his forehead. On his review of systems, his only complaint was "headache". The only physical findings were the hole in his forehead and blood in the back of his throat. Luckily it was a small caliber bullet, it went right down the middle missing everything important, and *he had swallowed it* after it exited the base of the skull. So... no. He didn't die.

Comment: @anongoodnurse this is really an interesting case !! Hope he's recovering well.

Comment: @anongoodnurse He ***ate*** the bullet after it had exited his skull? Or did it exit into his throat? Or am I misunderstanding you? Thanks for sharing either way - really interesting to hear.

Comment: @fileunderwater - It had exited the base of his skull at the back of his throat and he swallowed it (presumably in the gush of blood.) I found the bullet in his stomach when I did a pre-op chest xray along with xrays of his head. (This was a long, long time ago!) He stated he had never been shot before, so with the bone fragment locations and the history, that was the conclusion. I'm still amazed by the whole thing.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Ok, that makes more sense than eating it. Amazing story either way. Do you know if he recovered fully?

Comment: @MauroM - Charity was the busiest ER in the country when I was there. He didn't die while I was there, but he was kind of "lost to follow-up" (hard to keep track of.) I think he was fine, though.

Comment: @fileunderwater - As fully as we could tell. He was discharged to home without complications by neurosurgery/neurology. Can you imagine how easily it could have hit his spinal cord? Just amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.aans.org/Patient%20Information/Conditions%20and%20Treatments/Gunshot%20Wound%20Head%20Trauma.aspx) appearing on the website of the American Association of Neurological Surgeons, gunshot injuries to the head are fatal in 90 per cent of cases. Many victims die before reaching the ER, and the 50 per cent who survive the initial trauma die in the ER.

Answer (score 2):

The comments on this question have pretty much covered everything I had to say. *Generally*, you're more likely to cause brain damage than an instant kill by shooting someone in the head, though it does depend on what part of the brain is hit and the kind of projectile being used.

Normal small-caliber weapons pierce bone and tissue and that's about it. Small arms marksman training teaches you to focus on center of mass because you're more likely to get a kill by bleed-out or organ trauma than the considerably-more-difficult headshot.

WYSIWYG mentioned Phineas Gage in the comments, who survived having an iron bar driven through his skull [thusly](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Simulated_Connectivity_Damage_of_Phineas_Gage_vanHorn_ProbablePaths.jpg). He suffered a severe change of personality but was otherwise fairly functional. ([Full wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_Gage) contains sections on various studies about brain damage).

The idea of a headshot being an instant kill most likely comes from use of hollow-point bullets and/or high caliber weapons like sniper rifles. [Hollow-points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow-point_bullet) expand on contact with or shatter inside the target, causing much more damage than a normal bullet. The larger impact area of a hollow-point or the higher velocity of a powerful rifle are what cause the familiar "exploding skull" visual.

(An additional personal theory: since headshots are much more difficult to achieve due to the small target, I believe they are used as an instant-kill reward in a lot of video games, adding to the myth. Realistically the victim is severely disabled, making it equivalent to a kill in game-terms, but would likely recover given proper medical attention.)

The extent of the damage, however, depends on what part of the brain is hit. I'm not an expert on neurology so unfortunately I can't answer that aspect of the question. Blood and/or fluid entering the brain through the wound, however, could very likely be fatal.

In summary: small arms like a police handgun wouldn't likely cause an instant kill with a head-shot. For practical purposes, the probable instant *debilitation* of the target may count as a "kill" without technically being immediately lethal.

Comment: Small arms are perfectly capable of killing via headshot. You have to take the caliber, velocity, type of bullet, location of impact, distance from gun to target, and path of travel of the bullet into consideration. A shot just above the bridge of the nose will kill with anything from a 9mm on up, and would likely kill with a hollow-point .22 with sufficient velocity to pierce the frontal bone. Most police sidearms these days are relatively high-velocity 9mm, larger but slightly slower .40S&W, and the even larger .45, which while relatively the slowest can still easily penetrate and kill.